# CreateEvent initial state signaled is not signaling event

Tags: c++, windows, ipc, msdn, io-redirection

I am working on IO redirection program and i successfully created poc for it. The program spawn the child process and communicate with it using named pipes. I used Event object to get event whenever there is data on the pipe. I set the event to signaled state by default but i am not getting the event for the first time. To get the event i have to write on input pipe. When i write some command on input pipe i get the event and and get the output for the old command, not the current command(Please see the output).

below is the working code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define input_pipe_name L"\\\\.\\pipe\\input"
#define output_pipe_name L"\\\\.\\pipe\\output"
#define process_name L"cmd.exe"

HANDLE input_pipe_handle;
HANDLE output_pipe_handle;

HANDLE input_file_handle;
HANDLE output_file_handle;


OVERLAPPED output_overlapped = { 0 };

BOOL InitHandels()
{
    input_pipe_handle = CreateNamedPipe(input_pipe_name, PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT, 1, 4096, 4096, 120000, 0);
    SetHandleInformation(input_pipe_handle, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT);
    if (input_pipe_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        cout << "pipe creation error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
        return FALSE;
    }

    output_pipe_handle = CreateNamedPipe(output_pipe_name, PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT, 1, 4096, 4096, 120000, 0);
    SetHandleInformation(output_pipe_handle, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT);
    if (output_pipe_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        cout << "pipe creation error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
        return FALSE;
    }

    input_file_handle = CreateFile(input_pipe_name, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
    if (input_file_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        cout << "file creation error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
        return FALSE;
    }

    output_file_handle = CreateFile(output_pipe_name, GENERIC_READ, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
    if (output_file_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        cout << "file creation error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
        return FALSE;
    }

    output_overlapped.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, TRUE, NULL);
    ConnectNamedPipe(output_pipe_handle, &output_overlapped);
}



void CreateChildProcess()
{
    TCHAR szCmdline[] = L"cmd.exe";
    PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo;
    STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;

    ZeroMemory(&piProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    ZeroMemory(&siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    siStartInfo.hStdError = output_pipe_handle;
    siStartInfo.hStdOutput = output_pipe_handle;
    siStartInfo.hStdInput = input_pipe_handle;
    siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    if (!CreateProcess(NULL, szCmdline, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &siStartInfo, &piProcInfo))
    {
        cout << "process creation error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
        //return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        HANDLE h_array[] = {output_overlapped.hEvent, piProcInfo.hProcess};

        for (;;)
        {
            DWORD result = WaitForMultipleObjects(2, h_array, FALSE, 1000);
            DWORD bwritten = 0, bread = 0;
            char buffer[4096];

            switch (result)
            {
                case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
                    //cout << "TimeOut" << endl;
                    break;

                case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                    ReadFile(output_file_handle, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &bread, &output_overlapped);
                    WriteFile(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), buffer, bread, &bwritten, 0);
                    ResetEvent(output_overlapped.hEvent);
                    break;

                case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1: 
                    break;
                    //return FALSE;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    DWORD bwritten;
    InitHandels();
    //CreateChildProcess();
    std::thread t1(CreateChildProcess);
    for (;;Sleep(1000))
    {
        std::string mystring;
        std::cin >> mystring;
        mystring.append("\n");
        WriteFile(input_file_handle, mystring.c_str(), mystring.length(), &bwritten, &output_overlapped);
        //WriteFile(input_file_handle, "dir\n", 4, &bwritten, &output_overlapped);
    }
    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following output

```
dir
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

D:\Programming\VS\to_post_on_stack\to_post_on_stack>hello
dir
 Volume in drive D has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 54FB-7A94

 Directory of D:\Programming\VS\to_post_on_stack\to_post_on_stack

01/13/2018  05:36 PM    <DIR>          .
01/13/2018  05:36 PM    <DIR>          ..
01/13/2018  05:36 PM    <DIR>          Debug
01/12/2018  08:54 PM               608 stdafx.cpp
01/12/2018  08:54 PM               642 stdafx.h
01/12/2018  08:54 PM               630 targetver.h
01/13/2018  05:36 PM             7,434 to_post_on_stack.cpp
01/12/2018  08:54 PM             8,038 to_post_on_stack.vcxproj
01/12/2018  08:54 PM             1,277 to_post_on_stack.vcxproj.filters
               6 File(s)         18,629 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  39,347,019,776 bytes free

D:\Programming\VS\to_post_on_stack\to_post_on_stack>dir
hello
'hello' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\Programming\VS\to_post_on_stack\to_post_on_stack>dir
```

As you can see in the output when i send `dir` command i get the old output. When i send `hello` i get the output for the `dir` command which i executed before `hello`.

SO can anyone point out the mistake that why i am not getting signal for the very first time. And why the output is not getting in sequence?

Comment: you not need any separate event at all. you not need 2 pipe pair - but only one. you not need call `SetHandleInformation` - just create file handle as inherited

Comment: `WriteFile` just after asynchronous call `ReadFile` incorrect - data can be yet not ready - all code is wrong from begin to the end

Comment: you use the same `output_overlapped` in 2 api calls at once (`WriteFile(input_file_handle` and `ReadFile(output_file_handle`) - this is critical bug too - even io call must use it own overlapped - again - all code is wrong

Comment: @RbMm I am beginner to this. Could you please correct the mistakes and post it as answer? Please help

Comment: @RbMm Which one of the above bug is really causing problem?

Comment: you use the same output_overlapped in 2 api calls at once. but code is all wrong

Comment: okay, i will try with making changes in it. thank you..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163107/discussion-between-swapnil-and-rbmm).

Answer (score 2):

the code example full of critical bugs:

the first and main:

> If *hFile* was opened with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`, the following
>   conditions are in effect:
>
> The *lpOverlapped* parameter must point to a valid and **unique**
>   `OVERLAPPED` structure, otherwise the function can incorrectly report
>   that the io operation is complete.

and

> io operation **resets the event** specified by the *hEvent* member of the
>   `OVERLAPPED` structure to a nonsignaled state when it begins the I/O
>   operation. Therefore, the caller does not need to do that.

when io operation is complete - io subsystem write to *lpOverlapped* final status of operation, number of bytes transferred, and if it containing event - set this event to signal state. if you use the same *lpOverlapped* in concurrent - they overwrite result each other, and you never know - which operation is really complete - event is one, common !, also if you use event - system reset event before begin io - as result - one operation can complete and set event, then another operation reset it after this

you call in 2 threads in concurrent:

```
WriteFile(input_file_handle, ..&output_overlapped);
ReadFile(output_file_handle, .. &output_overlapped);
```

with this you already have UB because the same `&output_overlapped` used in concurrent. we need allocate unique overlapped to every operation. and if you use events for detect completion - you need create several events - this is not good way at all. much better use iocp completion here - we not need create events, we not need create separate thread.

```
ReadFile(output_file_handle, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &bread, &output_overlapped);
WriteFile(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), buffer, bread, &bwritten, 0);
ResetEvent(output_overlapped.hEvent);
```

at first `ReadFile` resets the event specified by the `hEvent` member of the `OVERLAPPED` structure to a nonsignaled state when it begins the I/O operation. Therefore, the caller does not need to do that. and more - when you call `ResetEvent` - operation can be already completed - so you reset already signaled event - and as result you lost completion signal. if call `ReasetEvent` this need do **before** io operation (`ReadFile` in concrete case) but not **after** - which is error. however we not need do this and before - because io subsystem anyway do this.

else one critical bug - we can not use `buffer, bread`in `WriteFile` just after **asynchronous** call to `ReadFile` - the call is can be not completed yet. and context of `buffer` yet not defined.

the `&bread` is undefined **always** in asynchronous call and must not be used at all

> The *lpNumberOfBytesRead* parameter should be set to **NULL**. Use the
>   `GetOverlappedResult` function to get the actual number of bytes read.
>   If the *hFile* parameter is associated with an I/O completion port,
>   you can also get the number of bytes read by calling the
>   *GetQueuedCompletionStatus* function.

else one very common mistake - that we create **2** pipe pairs (`input_pipe_handle`, `output_file_handle`) - this is absolute not need - we can use the **1** pipe pair.

the call to `SetHandleInformation` excess - we need just create handle with inherit properties via `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES`.

code example:

```
//#define _XP_SUPPORT_

struct IO_COUNT 
{
    HANDLE _hFile;
    HANDLE _hEvent;
    LONG _dwIoCount;

    IO_COUNT()
    {
        _dwIoCount = 1;
        _hEvent = 0;
    }

    ~IO_COUNT()
    {
        if (_hEvent)
        {
            CloseHandle(_hEvent);
        }
    }

    ULONG Create(HANDLE hFile);

    void BeginIo()
    {
        InterlockedIncrement(&_dwIoCount);
    }

    void EndIo()
    {
        if (!InterlockedDecrement(&_dwIoCount))
        {
            SetEvent(_hEvent);
        }
    }

    void Wait()
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(_hEvent, INFINITE);
    }
};

class U_IRP : OVERLAPPED 
{
    enum { connect, read, write  };

    IO_COUNT* _pIoObject;
    ULONG _code;
    LONG _dwRef;
    char _buffer[256];

    ~U_IRP()
    {
        _pIoObject->EndIo();
    }

    ULONG Read()
    {
        _code = read;

        AddRef();

        return CheckIoResult(ReadFile(_pIoObject->_hFile, _buffer, sizeof(_buffer), 0, this));
    }

    ULONG CheckIoResult(BOOL fOk)
    {
        if (fOk)
        {
#ifndef _XP_SUPPORT_
            OnIoComplete(NOERROR, InternalHigh);
#endif
            return NOERROR;
        }

        ULONG dwErrorCode = GetLastError();

        if (dwErrorCode != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
        {
            OnIoComplete(dwErrorCode, 0);
        }

        return dwErrorCode;
    }

    VOID OnIoComplete(DWORD dwErrorCode, DWORD_PTR dwNumberOfBytesTransfered)
    {
        switch (_code)
        {
        case connect:
            switch (dwErrorCode)
            {
            case ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED:
            case ERROR_NO_DATA:
                dwErrorCode = NOERROR;
            case NOERROR:
                Read();
            }
            break;

        case read:
            if (dwErrorCode == NOERROR)
            {
                if (dwNumberOfBytesTransfered)
                {
                    if (int cchWideChar = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_OEMCP, 0, _buffer, (ULONG)dwNumberOfBytesTransfered, 0, 0))
                    {
                        PWSTR wz = (PWSTR)alloca(cchWideChar * sizeof(WCHAR));

                        if (MultiByteToWideChar(CP_OEMCP, 0, _buffer, (ULONG)dwNumberOfBytesTransfered, wz, cchWideChar))
                        {
                            if (int cbMultiByte = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wz, cchWideChar, 0, 0, 0, 0))
                            {
                                PSTR sz = (PSTR)alloca(cbMultiByte);

                                if (WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wz, cchWideChar, sz, cbMultiByte, 0, 0))
                                {
                                    DbgPrint("%.*s", cbMultiByte, sz);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Read();
            }
            break;
        case write:
            break;
        default:
            __debugbreak();
        }

        Release();

        if (dwErrorCode)
        {
            DbgPrint("[%u]: error=%u\n", _code, dwErrorCode);
        }
    }

    static VOID WINAPI _OnIoComplete(
        DWORD dwErrorCode,
        DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,
        LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
        )
    {
        static_cast<U_IRP*>(lpOverlapped)->OnIoComplete(RtlNtStatusToDosError(dwErrorCode), dwNumberOfBytesTransfered);
    }

public:

    void AddRef()
    {
        InterlockedIncrement(&_dwRef);
    }

    void Release()
    {
        if (!InterlockedDecrement(&_dwRef)) delete this;
    }

    U_IRP(IO_COUNT* pIoObject) : _pIoObject(pIoObject)
    {
        _dwRef = 1;
        pIoObject->BeginIo();
        RtlZeroMemory(static_cast<OVERLAPPED*>(this), sizeof(OVERLAPPED));
    }

    ULONG Write(const void* pvBuffer, ULONG cbBuffer)
    {
        _code = write;

        AddRef();

        return CheckIoResult(WriteFile(_pIoObject->_hFile, pvBuffer, cbBuffer, 0, this));
    }

    ULONG Connect()
    {
        _code = connect;

        AddRef();

        return CheckIoResult(ConnectNamedPipe(_pIoObject->_hFile, this));
    }

    static ULONG Bind(HANDLE hFile)
    {
        return BindIoCompletionCallback(hFile, U_IRP::_OnIoComplete, 0)  
#ifndef _XP_SUPPORT_
            && SetFileCompletionNotificationModes(hFile, FILE_SKIP_COMPLETION_PORT_ON_SUCCESS)
#endif

        ? NOERROR : GetLastError();
    }
};

ULONG IO_COUNT::Create(HANDLE hFile)
{
    _hFile = hFile;
    if (_hEvent = CreateEvent(0, TRUE, FALSE, 0))
    {
        return U_IRP::Bind(hFile);
    }
    return GetLastError();
}

void ChildTest()
{
    static const WCHAR name[] = L"\\\\?\\pipe\\somename";

    HANDLE hFile = CreateNamedPipeW(name, 
        PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX|FILE_READ_DATA|FILE_WRITE_DATA|FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 
        PIPE_TYPE_BYTE|PIPE_READMODE_BYTE, 1, 0, 0, NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT, 0);

    if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        IO_COUNT obj;

        if (obj.Create(hFile) == NOERROR)
        {
            BOOL fOk = FALSE;

            static SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = { sizeof(sa), 0, TRUE };

            STARTUPINFOW si = { sizeof(si) };
            PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

            si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

            si.hStdError = CreateFileW(name, FILE_GENERIC_READ|FILE_GENERIC_WRITE, 
                FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE, &sa, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

            if (si.hStdError != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                si.hStdInput = si.hStdOutput = si.hStdError;

                WCHAR ApplicationName[MAX_PATH];
                if (GetEnvironmentVariableW(L"ComSpec", ApplicationName, RTL_NUMBER_OF(ApplicationName)))
                {
                    if (CreateProcessW(ApplicationName , 0, 0, 0, TRUE, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi))
                    {
                        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
                        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
                        fOk = TRUE;
                    }
                }

                CloseHandle(si.hStdError);
            }

            if (fOk)
            {
                U_IRP* p;

                if (p = new U_IRP(&obj))
                {
                    p->Connect();
                    p->Release();
                }

                obj.EndIo();

                //++ simulate user commands
                static PCSTR commands[] = { "dir\r\n", "ver\r\n", "exit\r\n" };
                ULONG n = RTL_NUMBER_OF(commands);
                PCSTR* psz = commands;
                do 
                {
                    if (p = new U_IRP(&obj))
                    {
                        PCSTR command = *psz++;
                        p->Write(command, (ULONG)strlen(command) * sizeof(CHAR));
                        p->Release();
                    }

                } while (--n);
                //--

                obj.Wait();
            }
        }

        CloseHandle(hFile);
    }
}
```